# Authenticated Request w/ Alamofire

Tags: swift, authentication, alamofire

I'm trying to make an authenticated request with Swift. When a user logs in, the authenticated header is set with the following:

```
    let user = userEmail
    let password = userPassword

    let plainString = "\(user):\(password)" as NSString
    let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64String = plainData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
```

In another controller, I'm trying to make an authenticated request, but it isn't working, here's the code:

```
 let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
 manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

 manager.request(.GET, "url")
        .responseJSON {(request, response, data, error) in

    }
```

I'm getting a 404 error because the authorization isn't being set in the header. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Alamofire add custom header to all requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758053/swift-alamofire-add-custom-header-to-all-requests)

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
let headers = [
            // write your header here
        ]

Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: headers).response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
}
```

Comment: please elaborate as to how this resolves the askers problem. remember that this post will be used as a resource by others in the future. recommended reading [answer]