# How to send request in Alamofire with parameters and headers using POST method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire, custom-headers

I have a problem with sending a request using `Alamofire`.
I want to send a POST request with parameters, but I don't know where to put custom header like token.

Here is my code:

```
let parameters = [
            "id": ID,
            "recipient_id" : recipientID,
            "is_match" : "1"
        ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Constants.baseURL + Constants.apiURL + Constants.accept, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            print(request)
            print(response)
            print(data)
            print(error)
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("Approve Successful")
                print("approve \(response)")


            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Btw I am using `Alamofire 3.4`

Comment: Duplicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758053/swift-alamofire-add-custom-header-to-all-requests)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alamofire 4.0

```
let headers = ["Content-Type":"Application/json"]


Alamofire.request(requestString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
                        print("Request  \(response.request)")

                    print("RESPONSE \(response.result.value)")
                    print("RESPONSE \(response.result)")
                    print("RESPONSE \(response)")


                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:


                        case .failure(let error):


                        }
                }
```

in 3.0 u can also add headers like this . In parameters to func